# Looking to manipulate a view into groups and add conditions - POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to take the difference of one column under a different classification and add it to another. Additionally, break them out into groups which would include different calculations. For example,

| Class | exclusion | exclude_spec | include_spec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nike |  | 1977 | 2008 |
| Converse |  | 89 | 184 |
| Converse | Dior | 500 | 550 |

And transform it into the following

| Class | Small | Medium | Large |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nike | 2008 | 2008 + (Include_Spec - Exclude_Spec for Converse) | 2008 + (Include_Spec - Exclude_Spec for Converse) |
| Converse | 184 | 184 | 184 + ( Converse Exclusion from include_spec column(550) |

I have used case expression and everything, but I am genuinely confused on the direction I should go to produce the table on the bottom. Any help is much appreciated!
-Currently using Postgresql

```
breakout as
(
select *, (inc_specialty - exclude_spec) as diff from class x where x.class = 'converse' and x.exclusion is NULL
)

SELECT *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN class = 'Nike'
        THEN include_spec  
        END AS small_group
    CASE 
        WHEN class = 'Nike' 
        THEN include_spec + (select diff from breakout)
        ELSE include_spec
        END AS medium_group
FROM class
```

That was the general approach I took towards creating the views. Apologies, if the post is not correct, it is my first time using Stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you really want the character string value "2008 + (Include_Spec - Exclude_Spec for Converse)"? Or does that describe the value you want to have calculated?

Comment: Hi, that was used to describe the value I want to have calculated. Sorry, if that was confusing